# Image preprocessing for pytesseract OCR using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, python-tesseract

I want to use pytesseract to create a captcha solver for images like these:

[image]

I used OpenCV to preprocess my image and so far I have the following:

Code:

```
import pytesseract
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('element.png')
ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
thresh1 = cv2.blur(thresh1, (5, 5))
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh1, lang='eng', config='-c tessedit_char_whitelist=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz --psm 6')
print(text)

cv2.imshow('Result1 bl', thresh1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result:

[image]

And pytesseract recognizes the text: SMVIN

What can I change or add to my code to get more accurate results?

Comment: captchas are hard to break for a reason...

Comment: I couldn't agree more. It's still an interesting problem.